# Cannot browse local Azure Storage Emulator in VS2013 - Azure SDK 2.4/2.5

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

When using the Server Explorer in VS2013, I cannot browse the Blob Storage under Development.
I receive this error:   "Failed To Connect To Microsoft Azure storage emulator"

I have started VS as Administrator.

I was having this issue using Azure SDK 2.4 so I updated to 2.5 and I am getting the same result.  However, I can browse the emulator using Azure Storage Explorer 6.

Any ideas?